# How to extract the result of a query from JSON inside a custom javascript function in OrientDB

Tags: javascript, json, orientdb

I created a custom javascript function in the OrientDB Studio. The function takes a rid as an argument and performs a select query from that rid.

```
var graph = orient.getGraph();
var res = graph.command( "sql", "select outE('Rel').inV('B').size() as lower_num from " + rid );
```

So, the result of this query  is a number. Depending on the value of this number the function should do different things. I wonder how to extract and use that value from the res variable inside the function. All my attempts have failed so far.. If I return the res variable from the function, the result looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "@type": "d",
   "@rid": "#-2:1",
   "@version": 0,
   "lower_num": 2
 }
]
```

So, I tried the following `( res[0]['lower_num'] == 2 ); ( res['lower_num'] == 2 )` and nothing worked.. They always returned false. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you want to do with the result? Extract in what type?

Comment: I need to extract the integer value of lower_num and compare it with some predefined integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrientDB put ODocument objects in the result set array. So try this:

```
return res[0].getRecord().field( "lower_num" );
```

Comment: In fact, it threw an exception
`Cannotfindfunctionfieldinobjectv(null)[
    #-2: 1
].`
But I modified it and the following worked
`return res[0].getRecord().field( "lower_num" );`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonhelp= [ { "@type": "d", "@rid": "#-2:1", "@version": 0, "lower_num": 2 } ];

var extractedNumber = jsonhelp[0].lower_num;
```

Now you can compare it with whatever you want; I hope it helps

like this you can extract any of the properties in JSON.

But in javascript there are two types of comparison

```
1) == simply compares values ,don't consider type
ex. '5' == 5 true , both are 5
     5 == 5 true.
2)=== considers type too
ex. '5' === 5 is false, different type i.e String === integer
     5 === 5 is true ,same type
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. I tried to return the following expression ```return( res[0].lower_num == 2 )``` from the function and it returned false

Comment: var jsonhelp= [ { "@type": "d", "@rid": "#-2:1", "@version": 0, "lower_num": 2 } ];

var ui = jsonhelp[0].lower_num;
 alert(ui ==  2);  try it, returns true. I have confirmed on jsfiddle.

Comment: Of course, what you said above is correct. But what I'm asking about here is how to extract the value from the res variable inside a javascript function in OrientDB when this variable contains the result of a query. When I return the variable itself ```return( res);``` I get this:
```[
     {
       "@type": "d",
       "@rid": "#-2:1",
       "@version": 0,
       "lower_num": 2
     }
   ]```
But, for some reason, the following ```return( res[0].lower_num )``` returns nothing. Perhaps, the res variable has some other internal structure..

Comment: Ok, now I am even more confused.. I tried to iterate over all enumerable properties of the res variable and saved them in an array. Then I returned that array from the function.
```
var graph = orient.getGraph();
var res = graph.command( "sql", "select outE('Rel').inV('B').size() as lower_num from " + rid );
var a = [];

for( p in res ) {
  a.push( p ); 
}

return( a );
```
The result was:
```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "value": [
            "0"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Then I tried to iterate over res[0]'s properties:
```
var graph = orient.getGraph();

var res = graph.command( "sql", "select outE('Rel').inV('B').size() as lower_num from " + rid );
var a = [];

for( p in res[0] ) {
  a.push( p ); 
}

return( a );
```

Comment: And I got this:
```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "value": [
            "getVertexInstance",
            "save",
            "getGraph",
            "propertyKeys",
            "vertices",
            "fromStream",
            "hashCode",
            "wait",
            "readExternal",
            "type",
            "toStream",
            "connectionClass",
            "isDetached"
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: So it's obvious that the res variable inside the function and the JSON I get when this variable is returned look different. But I still have no idea how to extract and use the lower_num value inside the function.