# Functions in OrientDB Studio - what is the correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, orientdb

We've spent some time trying to implement simple functions in the studio and the lack of documentation mixed with seemingly changing syntax makes things quite difficult. i.e.: orient.getGraph() function seems to work on 2.0.3 but not on 2.0.9 or 2.1-rc2.

Here is the code we have so far running on 2.0.3:

```
var mydb = orient.getGraph();

var nearbyNodes = mydb.command('sql',"select in('Contributes_To') from " +originNode);

return nearbyNodes;
```

Which returns:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:0",
        "@version": 0,
        "in": [
            "#13:1",
            "#13:0",
            "#13:3"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "in=z"
    }
]
```

I would like to get the values from the "in" key.

**QUESTION 1** - Is there an updated and reliable documentation source for JavaScript Studio Functions in OrientDB?

**QUESTION 2** - What is the correct way of doing an SQL command for newer versions (2.0.9 and 2.1-rc2)? The example above does not seem to work in new versions.

**QUESTION 3** - What is the correct way of handling the returned objects? As it was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657784/how-to-extract-the-result-of-a-query-from-json-inside-a-custom-javascript-functi) does not seem to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to find documentation around JavaScript API. However, in my research I actually went into the code which is responsible for managing the scripts in OrientDB.

For Graph DB, the class that manages the scripting is `com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.handler.OGraphServerHandler`. If you have a look at [this line](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/9c8c12bc1207e6607048ba94527bd1c09b32bcfa/graphdb/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/handler/OGraphServerHandler.java#L84) you can see that the variable "orient" is getting bound to an instance of [OScriptGraphOrientWrapper](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/script/OScriptGraphOrientWrapper.html)

In `OScriptGraphOrientWrapper` (javadoc link given above) you can see the getGraph() method actually returns an instance of [OScriptGraphWrapper](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/script/OScriptGraphWrapper.html)

In conclusion, when you actually execute a JavaScript function what actually gets invoked is the methods in the above mentioned Java classes (and many more). So you can refer to any method that's available in those classes, especially `OScriptGraphWrapper` and you can work on the actual return types of the methods in these classes.

I'm more in to Document Databases in OrientDB, this trick has actually worked for me. In other words, the JavaDoc is the API documentation. Hope this works for  you.

Cheers!

Omega

Comment: Thanks Omega! That's already some help. I'm able to do a query for the nearest neighbours through mydb.command("sql","select...", [])

Nevertheless I still get problems while trying to do something as simple as changing a simple INT parameter inside each of the returned nodes. Any tips on which function to use? I've tried to use mydb.command("sql", "update...", []) but Im not being able to inject the returned vertex ID's into the selection.

Comment: I tried to update an int value on a vertex in the GreatfulDeadConcerts database. Following is the code  <br/>   `var db = orient.getGraph();

var result = db.command("sql", "SELECT FROM V WHERE @rid = #9:2");  

print(result[0].getRecord().field("@rid"));

db.command("sql", "UPDATE V set performances = 10 WHERE @rid = " + result[0].getRecord().field("@rid"));`

Comment: Instead of V you can (and should!) specify the node directly by its @rid.

`db.command("sql", "UPDATE  " + result[0].getRecord().field("@rid") + " set performances = 10");`